# Element 'tr' cannot be nested within element 'tr'

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, html, validation

I have a partial view like this:

```cs
@model List<user>

@foreach (var user in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@user.name</td>
        <td>...</td>
    </tr>
}
```

And get an error like this:

> Validation (HTML5): Element 'tr' cannot be nested within element 'tr'.

It's annoying me more than it should, but I want to get rid of it. Installing [Web Standards Update](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a15c3ce9-f58f-42b7-8668-53f6cdc2cd83) didn't help. Any ideas?

**Edit**
This is the main view:

```cs
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>@i18n.name</th>
            <th>...</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="results">
        @Html.Partial("list_rows", @Model.users)
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is the generated HTML:

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>naam</th>
            <th>...</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="results">


<tr>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
</tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Edit** Pulling the entire page through the W3C validator gives

> This document was successfully checked as HTML5!

Comment: What does the generated HTML look like?

Comment: How does the code look like surrounding the partial view? Do you have an tr there as well?

Comment: @LockTar I've added the main view.

Comment: @TJ. I've added the generated HTML.

Comment: @Stijn Your generated HTML is perfectly valid.

Comment: I'll try to do this in VS 11 tonight and if the issue is still there, I'll file a bug on Connect.

Comment: Your code looks good. Does this problem also occur when you remove thead and tbody. It should not happen. I think it is a bug in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

This error appears when you open a `<tr>` element before you loop through your model. So far the code you postet is correct and free of errors.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that your code looks something like this:

```
<table>

@foreach (var user in Model)
{
     <tr>
          <td>@user.name</td>
          <td>...</td>
     </tr>
}

</table>
```

It seems like you already have an open tr tag in which you are trying to add more tr tags.  If you already have tr tags in your table, just make sure they are all closed before the loop starts:

```
<tr>..</tr>
```

Comment: I don't have an open `tr` tag anywhere else. The partial view doesn't have a `table` tag because I'm using infinite scrolling to load more rows via AJAX.

Comment: I ran your code through the HTML5 validator online and it validates as correct.  So I am just assuming it is something that Visual Studio is complaining about.  Where exactly do you get this error?  In the designer?

Comment: It shows up in the Error List pane as a Warning. I guess it's a bug and the only workaround is to disable the validation in Visual Studio?

Comment: I would just leave it there.  If I know that I am right then I will just leave it.